# Mac Pro Boot Camp Windows 7 AIM can't video chat with other Macs using iChat

Tags: mac, boot-camp, ichat, aim

I have a Mac Pro which I've bootcamped with Windows 7 64-bit. I cannot video chat with a colleague that is on a Mac using iChat.

I've tried both AIM Pro 1.5.0 and AIM 7.3.12.3 with no success. I am using a Linksys WRT54G-TM - I tried following the instructions listed below for opening ports for iChat but with no success:

[image]

I even tried opening up DMZ to my computer but this didn't work either. When a request is sent to me and I accept, it times out on my end and the other user receives a message saying I declined. When I initiate the request it sits there waiting for buddy confirmation on my end and it times out on their end. When I boot into the Mac side and use iChat there are no issues. I've tried completely disabling the Windows firewall with no success.

My colleague is using AIM through iChat - not a .Mac address. I have successfully video conferenced with another user via iChat v5.0.3 to AIM 7.3.12.3. This seems to me to be either an issue with the Windows firewall or possibly a networking issue at the ISP level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been unresolved. I am now just waiting for the Skype beta to be released for Mac so that my colleagues and I can switch over to using it. (Skype beta now supports multi-vid chat for Windows)

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses a custom implementation of RTP(Real-Time Transport Protocol). Therefore, iChat only works with other Mac OS X users. I recommend using Skype for VOIP.

Comment: That is not accurate, I've read on many forums that it is in fact possible to use AIM to iChat/Win to Mac with video. This article goes into detail on how to accomplish it http://www.mvldesign.com/video_conference_tutorial.html.

Comment: The article that you are referring to is unfortunately a little dated. While you are correct with your port forwarding, iChat v5.0.3 does not video chat via AIM with Windows clients. Since you are using AIM, your colleague can download AIM for Mac and you should be able to video chat. Apple's system requirements for iChat AV state Leopard compatible Macs only: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2020

Comment: Again that information is inaccurate, I've tried this on my LAN between my machine booted into Snow Leopard with iChat v5.0.3 and have successfully had video conferences with another machine running Windows 7 64-bit. I am not looking for whether this is possible or not since I know for a fact that it is. I came here looking for assistance troubleshooting what seems like either a firewall/networking issue.

Comment: I rechecked your port forwarding and noticed that you don't have XMPP(Jabber) configured. It is on port 5222(TCP).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...at this point I think it's beyond the realm of my router. I can connect to another user in the same state, but not outside of my state. The user I can connect to can connect to others, at this point I am going to contact my ISP to see if they are blocking the required ports. Again thank you for your assistance, I will post a follow up on my results.